# How can I disable the Magento shopping cart

Tags: cart, shopping-cart, core

How can I disable the Magento shopping cart.

I need to disable the Magento shopping cart.

Should I use the advanced settings of Magento or should I edit the config file?

Comment: Sebastien, do you want to only disable cart or the whole checkout logic?

Comment: Have you thought about simply removing the add to cart buttons on your pages?

Comment: ... or perhaps doing a redirect on the shopping cart page itself (say, back to the home page)?

Answer (score 4):

Why not disable via System > Configuration > Advanced > disable Mage_checkout

Answer (score 2):

Sebastien, you may use [Zookal Mock Object](https://github.com/Zookal/magento-mock) extension which will let you disable `Mage_Checkout` core module without breaking Magento completely.

You will need to do following:

1. Install extension Zookal Mock
2. Disable `Mage_Checkout` module and other modules which depend on it by adding following content in new file in `app/etc/modules/` eg. `Yourmodule_All.xml`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>
       <modules>
           <Mage_Checkout>
               <active>false</active>
           </Mage_Checkout>
           <Mage_Persistent>
               <active>false</active>
           </Mage_Persistent>
           <Mage_Paypal>
               <active>false</active>
           </Mage_Paypal>
           <Mage_PaypalUk>
               <active>false</active>
           </Mage_PaypalUk>
           <Mage_Authorizenet>
               <active>false</active>
           </Mage_Authorizenet>
           <Mage_Centinel>
               <active>false</active>
           </Mage_Centinel>
           <Mage_XmlConnect>
               <active>false</active>
           </Mage_XmlConnect>
       </modules>
   </config>
   ```

This should disable the whole checkout logic as well as it should remove some links pointing to checkout.

3. Edit template files to remove not needed links and logic pointing to cart eg. "Add to Cart" buttons, "Reorder" links etc.

Wishlist should work normally.